# How to use userultra plugin with page template in wordoress

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I have a problem with usersultra plugin for wordpress.

```
I have  created a template page for search, but i only want to display it for the client who is logged in, how can i use usersultra for this case.

Secondly when i check 'Only Logged in Users' checkbox in page settings it displays the content of my page and form of registration at the same time.

Please how can i resolve this problem.
```

EDIT :

this is what am trying but it doesn't work

```
<?php echo do_shortcode("[usersultra_protect_content display_rule='logged_in_based'  custom_message_loggedin='Only Logged in users can see the content']

    <b>myfield :</b><?php the_field('myfield');?>

[/usersultra_protect_content]"); ?>
```

it only shows the text not the value.

EDIT 2 :

it worked with the code Ahmed provided

```
<?php echo do_shortcode("[usersultra_protect_content display_rule='logged_in_based'  custom_message_loggedin='Only Logged in users can see the content']

        <b>myfield :</b>".the_field('myfield')."

    [/usersultra_protect_content]"); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that via this shortcode,

```
<?php echo do_shortcode("[usersultra_protect_content display_rule='logged_in_based'  custom_message_loggedin='Only Logged in users can see the content']Your private content here [/usersultra_protect_content]"); ?>
```

The shortcode is listed here on documentation page : https://usersultra.com/userultra/

Comment: how can i use this shortcode in a .php page. since am using a custom template that i created.

Comment: It Worked. i realy appreciate it, May Allah bless you.

Comment: Thank you :) , mark it as right answer if it worked for you so it helps other users too :) :)

Comment: @Ahemd Ginani i ran into a second problem, how can i add fields inside this code.

Comment: you can use : optional_fields_to_display='social' inside shortcode

Comment: please check the edit i made i explain my problem there

Comment: try echo get_the_field('myfield');

Comment: wait , it will work like this ".get_the_field('myfield')." don't use echo tags , 

<b>myfield :</b>".the_field('myfield')."

Comment: Glad to help :)